# construct 2d array to emulate a linked list

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, 2d

I would like to create a doubly linked list without using the Java linked list object.  I want to see if I can do so with a two dimensional array in which:

- the first dimension is the entry, and
- the second dimension is the forward pointer, the backward pointer, and the value of the node.

Here is what I'd like to display but not sure if I'm doing it correctly

1. add a node
2. remove a node from the middle of the list
3. add a node to the middle of the list
4. swap the first and last nodes of the linked list.

Here's my code, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class TwoDArrayLinkedList {

static class Node {
    Node forwardPointer;
    Node backwardPointer;
    int data;
}

static void display(Node head) {
    Node RightPointer;
    Node LeftPointer = head;

    while (LeftPointer != null) {
        RightPointer = LeftPointer;

        while (RightPointer != null) {
            System.out.print(RightPointer.data + " ");
            RightPointer = RightPointer.forwardPointer;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        LeftPointer = LeftPointer.backwardPointer;
    }
}

static Node construct(int array[][], int i, int j, int m, int n) {

    if (i > n - 1 || j > m - 1)
        return null;

    Node tempNode = new Node();
    tempNode.data = array[i][j];
    tempNode.forwardPointer = construct(array, i, j + 1, m, n);
    tempNode.backwardPointer = construct(array, i + 1, j, m, n);
    return tempNode;
    }


public static void main(String args[]) {
        int array[][] = { { 12, 22, 33 },
                    { 44, 54, 61 },
                   { 72, 82, 93 } };
    int m = 3, n = 3;
    Node head = construct(array, 0, 0, m, n);
    display(head);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour to this site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [ask a question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) At the moment it's unclear what you're asking from us.

Comment: Thanks, yacc.  My question is how do I :   1) add a node 2) remove a node from the middle of the list 3) add a node to the middle of the list 4) swap the first and last nodes of the linked list. I feel like I'm not accomplishing 2, 3, and 4 in my code at this point. Thanks for the help and the warm welcome!

Comment: Avoid asking multiple questions in one. The item list is too broad to elicit a precise answer. You may want to ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for opinions or improvement.

Answer (score 0):

[you are doing this ?](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-linked-list-2d-matrix/)

you aren't making it doubly-linked list you have written code for a linked list matrix such that each node is connected to its next right and down node.

to make 2D array as a doubly linked list you need to traverse each 2D Array element and needs to create a new node for each value and assign forward and backward reference. [this might help you](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/157583/converting-a-2d-array-into-a-2d-linked-list)